# UnboundLocalError with operators and functional programming in python (methods work fine)

Tags: python, functional-programming, operators

prog1.py:

```
def runf(f):
    f()

def main():
    l = [0]
    def f():
        l.append(1)
    runf(f)
    print(l)

main()
```

Gives me (as expected):

```
[0, 1]
```

prog2.py:

```
def runf(f):
    f()

def main():
    l = [0]
    def f():
        l += [1] # <-- Only difference
    runf(f)
    print(l)

main()
```

Gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog2.py", line 11, in <module>
    main()
  File "prog2.py", line 8, in main
    runf(f)
  File "prog2.py", line 2, in runf
    f()
  File "prog2.py", line 7, in f
    l += [1]
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'l' referenced before assignment
```

Could someone please explain to me what's going on here?

Note: This happens in both python2 and python3.

Also, I'm open to suggestions on a better title for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [execution model reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/executionmodel.html) of Python (section 4.1) states:

> If a name is bound in a block, it is a
>   local variable of that block.

What happens is that `l += [1]`, for the sake of binding is equivalent to `l = l + [1]`  which means `l` is *bound* inside `f`. Here's another interesting [document reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html):

> Assignment of an object to a single target is recursively defined as follows.
>
> If the target is an identifier (name):
>
> - If the name does not occur in a global statement in the current code
>     block: the name is bound to the object
>     in the current local namespace.
> - Otherwise: the name is bound to the object in the current global
>     namespace.

The *otherwise* clause is relevant here. Since you did not declare `global l` in the scope of `f` and assigned to `l`, the name is bound in the local namespace of `f`. Then, the reference to it implicitly created by `l += [1]` refers to a variable that hasn't been defined yet. Hence the `UnboundLocalError`.

---

P.S. `global l` wouldn't help you, by the way. Python 3 has the `nonlocal` statement to handle cases like this:

> The nonlocal statement causes the
>   listed identifiers to refer to
>   previously bound variables in the
>   nearest enclosing scope. This is
>   important because the default behavior
>   for binding is to search the local
>   namespace first. The statement allows
>   encapsulated code to rebind variables
>   outside of the local scope besides the
>   global (module) scope.

Comment: `a += b` *is not* exactly equivalent to `a = a + b`. It can be overloaded by `a` and in fact does in-place modification when possible.

Comment: @delnan: true, but for the sake of this question/answer, it *is* the same - augmented assignment statements (of which `+=` is part) are equivalent to assignment statements for the sake of scoping resolution

Comment: Then put it that way. As it stands now, the answer contains misinformation.